# Got time out error when mounting NFS

Tags: networking, 18.04, nfs

NFS server IP is 192.168.0.70, and NFS client IP is 192.168.0.84.
My `/etc/exports` file just like this:

```
/my/share/dir 192.168.0.84(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

And I use below commend to mounting:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.0.70:/my/share/dir /mnt/my_mount
```

The error message is:

```
username@client84:~$ sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.0.70:/src_dir/ /home/username/mount_point/
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

And the status of NFS serverm is:

```
username@server70:~$ systemctl status nfs-kernel-server.service 
● nfs-kernel-server.service - LSB: Kernel NFS server support
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-01-08 15:04:49 CST; 19h ago
  Process: 7199 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7209 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I tried capture package on NFS server, and this is what I got:

```
15:09:43.563798 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 54562, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.760 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0x794a (correct), seq 1313175943, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280514213 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:09:43.563826 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24797, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.760: Flags [R.], cksum 0xc358 (correct), seq 0, ack 1313175944, win 0, length 0
15:09:44.564453 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 3109, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.926 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0xdeea (correct), seq 3201409466, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280514463 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:09:44.564485 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24971, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.926: Flags [R.], cksum 0x29f3 (correct), seq 0, ack 3201409467, win 0, length 0
15:09:46.565080 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20545, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.979 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0xef6c (correct), seq 1309605842, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280514963 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:09:46.565101 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25141, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.979: Flags [R.], cksum 0x3c69 (correct), seq 0, ack 1309605843, win 0, length 0
15:09:48.565600 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.0.70 tell 192.168.0.84, length 46
15:09:48.565630 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.0.70 is-at aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, length 28
15:09:50.565751 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 27321, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.861 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0x3093 (correct), seq 797104581, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280515964 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:09:50.565779 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25423, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.861: Flags [R.], cksumARP 0x8178 (correct), seq 0, ack 797104582, win 0, length 0
15:09:55.579799 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.0.84 tell 192.168.0.70, length 28
15:09:55.580001 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.0.84 is-at aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, length 46
15:09:58.566416 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 36260, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.959 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0x15eb (correct), seq 3839178472, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280517964 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:09:58.566449 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26424, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.959: Flags [R.], cksum 0x6ea0 (correct), seq 0, ack 3839178473, win 0, length 0
15:10:08.567151 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40969, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.889 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0x067e (correct), seq 3163776281, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280520464 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:10:08.567203 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26636, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.889: Flags [R.], cksum 0x68f7 (correct), seq 0, ack 3163776282, win 0, length 0
15:10:18.567873 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 4325, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.671 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0xf5c0 (correct), seq 1263459889, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280522964 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:10:18.567897 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 27229, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.671: Flags [R.], cksum 0x61fe (correct), seq 0, ack 1263459890, win 0, length 0
15:10:28.568630 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38694, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.853 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0x9aff (correct), seq 705253310, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280525464 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:10:28.568665 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29520, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.853: Flags [R.], cksum 0x1101 (correct), seq 0, ack 705253311, win 0, length 0
15:10:38.569313 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40959, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.929 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0x8924 (correct), seq 66026915, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280527964 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:10:38.569343 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31363, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.929: Flags [R.], cksum 0x08ea (correct), seq 0, ack 66026916, win 0, length 0
15:10:43.573606 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.0.70 tell 192.168.0.84, length 46
15:10:43.573620 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.0.70 is-at aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, length 28
15:10:48.570034 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25891, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.722 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0x687f (correct), seq 272599298, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280530465 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:10:48.570077 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 32321, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.722: Flags [R.], cksum 0xf209 (correct), seq 0, ack 272599299, win 0, length 0
15:10:53.579804 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.0.84 tell 192.168.0.70, length 28
15:10:53.580011 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.0.84 is-at aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, length 46
15:10:58.570709 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41869, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.749 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0x7edd (correct), seq 580671080, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280532965 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:10:58.570731 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 32668, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.749: Flags [R.], cksum 0x122c (correct), seq 0, ack 580671081, win 0, length 0
15:11:08.571380 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 3221, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.817 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0xf10d (correct), seq 160428860, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280535465 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:11:08.571416 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 33817, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.817: Flags [R.], cksum 0x8e20 (correct), seq 0, ack 160428861, win 0, length 0
15:11:18.572069 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47816, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.753 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0xb122 (correct), seq 2139992997, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280537965 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:11:18.572107 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34217, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.753: Flags [R.], cksum 0x57f9 (correct), seq 0, ack 2139992998, win 0, length 0
15:11:28.572748 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 64308, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.867 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0x9ade (correct), seq 1463543813, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280540465 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:11:28.572775 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 36325, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.867: Flags [R.], cksum 0x4b79 (correct), seq 0, ack 1463543814, win 0, length 0
15:11:33.579799 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.0.84 tell 192.168.0.70, length 28
15:11:33.580030 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.0.84 is-at aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, length 46
15:11:38.573414 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63669, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.920 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0xf76b (correct), seq 4101628992, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280542965 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:11:38.573440 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38585, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.920: Flags [R.], cksum 0xb1ca (correct), seq 0, ack 4101628993, win 0, length 0
15:11:48.574103 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28920, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.0.84.769 > 192.168.0.70.2049: Flags [S], cksum 0xb826 (correct), seq 3096401474, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3280545466 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:11:48.574137 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38789, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.0.70.2049 > 192.168.0.84.769: Flags [R.], cksum 0x7c4a (correct), seq 0, ack 3096401475, win 0, length 0
```

Please give me some advice, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please add the specific error message you get on the client when trying to mount the volume? Also, can you verify, that NFS is running on your server?

Comment: @StrabagISS_Krall Thanks for your comment, and I append some information.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused why systemd shows a status of `active (exited)`.
Could you please confirm if `nfsd` is running by executing `ps aux | grep -i nfsd`?

Comment: @StrabagISS_Krall Oh, the nfsd is not running. It is the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the solution to the problem:

- Make sure that NFSD is enabled in systemd by running `systemctl status nfs-kernel-server.service`
- Make sure that NFSD is actually running by executing `ps aux | grep -i nfsd`

Comment: In my case, `nfs-kernel-server` and `nfsd` were up and running. I had to allow `2049` (default port for `nfs`) with `sudo ufw allow 2049` command into my firewall setting.